# Change boolean value on iOS swipe action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have a table that is showing items on a customers wish list. They can move the wished item off the list and into their collection using the "Move to Collection" button. This button is a boolean value.

How can I change that value from true to false?

Here is my Swift code:

```
let moveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Move to Collection",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
        //Change the boolean of the collection to false.
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let friendToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)
        context.delete(friendToDelete)

        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
})
```

Comment: You have the `indexPath` of the row where the button was tapped, so how you can you _not_ know how to change whatever the desired value is?

Comment: You can get a managed object from the `indexPath` and update your value to `true` or `false`. When you’re done? Simple save it!

Comment: Can I run that save as "@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {}"  This is how I'm saving the data to my CoreData table when a record is being made.

Comment: @M.Shaver Your initial value is `true`?

Comment: @Mannopson the value is true and on the swipe to left when user taps "Move to Collection", the value needs to be turned to false, reload the table and the item moves into their "Collection".  This table is governed by the WishList boolean being true.  Please help or advise.

Comment: @M.Shaver I’m sorry. I misunderstand your question. I can help you, but I need some details and what’s your main design goal?

Comment: @Mannopson I have the Xcode project in a share DropBox if you'd like to get a look.  I just need a fresh set of eyes.   The boolean that governs the wish listed item is toggled to "true". There is a "wish list" icon, and if tapped users will see their current wish list.   Using the swipe left, you can see there is a blue button option that says, "Move to Collection".    How can I change the value of that boolean from true -> false when they tap it?  This data is kept in a CoreData framework.  Please help.  I have the DropBox link if you would like a look.

Comment: @M.Shaver Ok! Give me the Dropbox link

Comment: @Mannopson https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h777vynkol60tcs/AADkG5s7CSB9qXPa0Kng6yu-a?dl=0

Comment: @Mannopson Thank you!  I'll try this out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
let moveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Move to Collection",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {

let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let managedObject = self.fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)

// Change the boolean of the collection to false.
managedObject.setValue(false, forKey: "yourKey") // managedObject.wish = false
//...

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
      }
}
})
```

So, get your managed object from the `indexPath`. And give the new values to managed object, that’s it. Simply save changes. Let me know if it’s works.